# Import/convert my date column from Excel into a datetime datatype in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I am importing an Excel file in CSV format. The file has 1,048,576 rows.
So far I have not been able to import the file with `datetime` datatype or convert/cast the columns with dates to `datetime` data types. I can only import the date column as a `nvarchar`, `varchar` or `sql variant`. The only time I can convert the column is if the file is under 71000 rows. Otherwise I get an error that the conversion from string is out of range or failed. (Please see below for pictures and more detail)

I have tried the following

- Casting or converting the columns
- Changing the data type via the table design
- Importing with date time datatype
- Copy and paste the data to a datetime column
- Checking and converting the date column in excel, before importing
- Batch Inserting the document
- Importing as a text file
- Removing null columns in the excel file
- Importing as non string variable
- Creating a temporary table
- Making temporary variables with datetime data types

---

Notes

1. I am using the developer edition of sql server
2. I am trying to get the date columns(transaction_date, date_created) into a
   date time datatype, I can only have them as a narvchar datatype currently

**How I Import The CSV File**
[Right clicking database, clicking task and import flat file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PDFK.png)

**Error Messages**
[Error message when trying to convert via table design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjZXj.png)
[Error message when importing csv file to sql server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caKdr.png)

**Sample of The CSV File**
[Sample of the CSV File Showing About 10 Rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7VBK.png)

**Database Schema**
[Brief Synopsis of Desired Database, Trying to Get Date Columns to DateTime Data type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xvfP.png)

Comment: `The file has 1,048,576 files` Really ?

Comment: How do you import the `CSV` `file` or `files` into `SQL Server` ?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. The table has 1,048,576 rows.

Comment: I use a flat file import to import the file from excel to sql server

Comment: Technically, `CSV` is not a `Excel` file. `Excel` happens to be able to open the `CSV` format. You have not provide much information for us to help you. `1` How do you import the `CSV` into a table in `SQL Server`. `2` Sample content from the `CSV` file. `3` Destination table schema. `4` Exact error message

Comment: @Squirrel I will update the question with more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Function SQLDate(d)
SQLDate = WorksheetFunction.Text(d, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss")
End Function
```

Note: "d" refers to date field.

Alternatively, you could convert Excel data to string:

```
TEXT(d,"dd mmmm yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

Then convert as req. from within SQL. For further clarity in this regard - see screenshot below.

[image: Depiction of how to format date field (in Excel) prior to import]

Citation: Thanks to [H Javed](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1066531/How-to-convert-Date-format-of-Excel-to-Sql-Date-fo)

Comment: I am getting an error, using this solution? Can you please define your variables d and WorksheetFunction? Are these defined by the user? Is this a VBA function or SQL query?

Comment: for TEXT(d,"dd mmmm yyyy hh:mm:ss") - this would be in excel, a function you use to convert the date field data into before hand - i.e. before importing via SQL. Per context, and d = date (assumes you have access to Excel data before-hand and can manipulate as req.) See updated post.  Let me know if further clarification required.  PS-  did you try the SQL code?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have tried converting the date format prior to importing a few times and still received an error. I will try your sql code again!

Comment: what error do you receive? per screenshot- there's nothing wrong with the excel formula so if you're receiving an error at this point (within excel) something is going wrong with how you apply the formula. RE: SQL code-  what error do you get? is it how you are defining 'd' ?

Comment: My excel is working my sql server is where I am having errors. I tried converting the columns to a different date format and that seemed to help. Thank  you for your help!

Comment: I tried, but i'm new so it's not showing up yet :-)